# I'm receiving this error when I point my domain names to a new VPS host: "You must enter a registered nameserver"

Tags: domains, dns, vps, nameserver

Why am I getting this error message when I point my domain names from my old host to a new VPS host:

[image]

**knowing that My dns is already registered in my new VPS host!**

[image]

Comment: Have you registered the nameservers at the domain registrar ? Assuming you have switched hosts and your nameservers are now on a separate IP you will have to update the GLUE records at the registar. ALso do your nameservers have A records ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the nameservers since you can just update the A record IP address and in `ftp` `cpanel` `webdisk` `whm` `mail` put a `@`.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if your nameservers can be found here: [InterNic Whois Search](http://www.internic.net/whois.html)

- Select "Nameserver"
- Enter your nameservers like:  `ns1.yourdomain.com` and click Search

If found, that will return its IP address and your registrar. If it can't be found, then repeat the search using "Domain" instead to lookup or confirm your registrar.

Next, log into your account at your registrar and either edit your nameserver's IP address to match the IP address of where it's located, or register new ones if missing from the search above. See the last link [here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names#registering) for example instructions how to do this at one major registrar. cPanel also provides instructions for other registrars here:  [How to Register Private Nameservers](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/RegNameserver)

If you're hosting your own nameservers on the same server as your website(s) (as it appears you are), then the IP address for the nameservers should be the same as the IP address of your domain's `A` record.

You will also have to create `A` records for each nameserver in your control panel using your IP address. See the following article on how to do that:  [Setting Up Private Nameservers in WHM/cPanel](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/setting-up-private-nameservers-in-whmcpanel/)

Note that registering and editing nameservers will take time to propagate throughout the Internet (up to 72 hours), so you site may not be accessible everywhere right away.